# Laravel site wrongly redirecting to site.com/public/public

Tags: laravel, redirect

I deployed my `laravel` project on my hosting `service: one.com.` The problem is that when I connect to the website, it redirects me to `site.com/public/public`. This isn't neccesary because `index.php` is not in the `public/public` directory.
If I go to `site.com/index.php`, everything works as intended.

I already tried to change the `.htaccess` file, but this doesn't solve anything.

This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

If it helps, this is my filestructure:

[Filestructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCVVw.png)

Comment: can please you add apache/Nginx server configuration also?

Comment: Where can I find this on a shared hosting site?